# postgres + node + angular: problems with utf-8 and queries with chinese characters

Tags: angularjs, node.js, encoding, utf-8

within a small sample application I tried to deal with non-latin characters. So I have a PostgreSQL DB 9.4, a NodeJS server and use Angular for the client side. In Postgres I have a simple table 'name' with a collection of english, russian and chinese names (with latin/cyrillic/chinese utf-8 characters).

The problem is, if I send REST requests from the browser (using within a SELECT-WHERE-LIKE query to Postgres), I get right query responses for english terms, but not for chinese terms. With non-latin characters within the REST string I always get nothing.

- Postgres is set to UTF-8 (with char type 'C')
- queries done in pgAdmin work well with latin/cyrillic/chinese characters
- in Node I set for Postgres: client.client_encoding = 'UTF8';
- and also for HTTP Responses: res.writeHead(200, {'content-type':'application/json','charset':'utf-8','content-length':Buffer.byteLength(json)});
- the Browser tells me for my HTML/Angular page: Encoding UTF-8

What I found is, Node receives something like '/dataload/name?%E9%82%A3%E4%BD%95' instead of '/dataload/name?那何'. And of course if I use this within a LIKE query it comes to LIKE %%E9%82%A3%E4%BD%95% and clearly will not work. But where I forgot something? What I have to do to let Node receive correct UTF-8 characters? Btw I use Webstorm/Windows for development. Should I provide more informations? I guess Postgres is set ok, but there is something to set in the Browser or in Angular code ... ?
Thanks in advance for any hint!

Update:

I just added header configuration in the Angular request:

```
$http.get(strReq, {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
    })
```

But the problem still exist. Firebug tells me this:

```
GET http://.../dataload/name?%E9%82%A3%E4%BD%95
```

With this Request Header:
    Accept  application/json, text/plain, */*
    Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
    Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
    DNT 1
    Host    localhost
    User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0

But as Parameter correctly: 那何

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things.

1. RFC3986 defines what characters can be in a url, and it's basically a short list.  Anything that doesn't fit in that list has to be expressed as url encoded characters (the %E9, etc etc).  So what you're receiving on the server looks like it's been properly encoded for a url.
2. If you do a POST, there's more latitude in the mime types as to how it gets passed.
3. The declared page encoding (either in the charset header or a meta html header) is what usually determines how the browser is going to package your inputs - even more than how it reads the html it got.  Having declared utf8, your chinese characters will actually be serialized as you're seeing (except %xx will by the actual corresponding byte value).  Your browser just knows how to present that as 2 chinese characters.  You could have declared utf16, but last time I tested it browsers were kinda wonky on how they handled that.

The upshot is that you need to do a url decode on your server side first, or use a framework that would have already done that for you.